# jQuery imgAreaSelect create thumbnail

Tags: php, jquery, img-area-select-jquery

I am using a jQuery plugin http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/ that allows cropping of an image.

I have search high and low for a tutorial that allows me to over write the file on the server with the cropped version...but found nothing of use.

I am using the basic integration of the plugin inside Facebox. This is working fine.

I have a button on the page which says 'Save', when that is clicked I would like to store the new image (cropped) on the server.

Any suggestions or need further information?

Comment: The plugin doesn't actually do any cropping, merely gives you co-ordinates of an image that you could use to then pass to PHP or another server side language, that could crop the image for you

Comment: Yeah thanks. I just worked that out...problem is, I dont know how to process the co-ordinates to produce a new image. Maybe some more searching might uncover something. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this awesome [tutorial](http://www.webmotionuk.co.uk/jquery/image_upload_crop.php)

Comment: The tutorial isn't awesome at all. It is really messy code. However, it does show a way how you can achieve what you want. The cropped image isn't uploaded, but cropped again server side with the posted dimensions and coordinates. I upvoted this answer.

Answer (score 2):

I use Jcrop for my projects works great! 
http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html

http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=live_crop <--

Comment: This answer should be downvoted. It is not what Puks1978 asked for. And also with this jquery plugin, the cropped image is not uploaded, but reproduced server side.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at the links at the very bottom of the plugin page? There are some useful links including [this one](http://www.leonkessler.com/blog/?p=132). It should help you get started with the php side of things

Comment: Yeah I did but I broke my page. I will give it a retry.

Comment: @RWC seems the guys whole site content has gone missing

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the that image I was uploading was bigger than the area size of the cropping tool.

Image was 1024x768 however I resized the image to fit within 500x500 overlay.

I will need to resize and save new sized image during the upload.

Thanks for all your suggestions.